# Add column to show of days since created

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I am using sharepoint 2010
I have list and I want to add column to show of days since item created
 I do not know how I can do this 
can you help me

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with help of Calculated columns.

Refer this article to understand to Syntax of it [here](http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/calculated-columns-tutorial).

Also this blog post by Keith Tuomi {[MVP](http://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/MVP/Keith%20Tuomi-5000238)} will help you understand the different type of calculated column formulas here: [SharePoint Calculated Column Formulas & Functions](http://yalla.itgroove.net/2012/09/20/sharepoint-calculated-column-formulas/).

Hope you get your solution.